# Split string at quotes

Tags: zsh

My use case: `bw unlock 'my password'` outputs several lines one of them starting with `$ export BW_SESSION="`. I want to save what comes after between quotes into a variable called BW_SESSION.

Example `bw unlock` output:

```
Your vault is now unlocked!

To unlock your vault, set your session key to the `BW_SESSION` environment variable. ex:
$ export BW_SESSION="0d7hzk3i9UaX0Pbq9YlG5VG11ozOGZQ1o304orui1orxHeh7Lk2GIqWCcFN3+hnpMnHqIGjqOlsgQ5tgaI9w1A=="
> $env:BW_SESSION="0d7hzk3i9UaX0Pbq9YlG5VG11ozOGZQ1o304orui1orxHeh7Lk2GIqWCcFN3+hnpMnHqIGjqOlsgQ5tgaI9w1A=="

You can also pass the session key to any command with the `--session` option. ex:
$ bw list items --session 0d7hzk3i9UaX0Pbq9YlG5VG11ozOGZQ1o304orui1orxHeh7Lk2GIqWCcFN3+hnpMnHqIGjqOlsgQ5tgaI9w1A==
```

My attempt:

```
lineWithSessionID=$(bw unlock 'my password' |  grep '$ export BW_SESSION="') ;
quotesToSpaces=(${(s/\"/)lineWithSessionID}) ;
splitOnSpaces=(${(s/ /)quotesToSpaces}) ; 
BW_SESSION=$splitOnSpaces[4] ;
echo $BW_SESSION
```

I was expecting `quotesToSpaces=(${(s/\"/)lineWithSessionID})` to actually do the job and split a string at the quotes, but it is intermittently substituting the quotes with spaces, and not working at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are thinking too complicated: Just do another regex match:

```
if [[ $lineWithSessionID =~ \"(.*)\" ]] 
then
  BW_SESSION=$match[1]
else
  echo Unexpected content: $lineWithSessionID 
fi
```

If you are brave and really can trust the output `bw unlock`, you can even do a

```
eval $lineWithSessionID[3,-1]
```

Which sets `BW_SESSION` and also puts it into the environment, but of course comes with all the perils of `eval`....